# How to click on Recycler View in Android and get Another dataActivity like playstore?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I have try to implement on Bind() in Recycelr view.
I am creating a vertical recycler view but i cant find on click handling on a particular section and cannot implimented intent to a uniue activity like playstore.

package com.example.bhupi.anyfreemovie.MovieRecycleSession;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.bhupi.anyfreemovie.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewDataAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewDataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        ItemRowHolder mh = new ItemRowHolder(v);
        return mh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemRowHolder itemRowHolder, int i) {

        final String sectionName = dataList.get(i).getHeaderTitle();

        ArrayList singleSectionItems = dataList.get(i).getAllItemsInSection();

        itemRowHolder.itemTitle.setText(sectionName);

        SectionListDataAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new SectionListDataAdapter(mContext, singleSectionItems);

        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);


        itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);


       /*  itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        //Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events once again.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }
                // Handle RecyclerView touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });*/

        itemRowHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Movies are Loading , " + sectionName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent


            }
        });







       /* Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .centerCrop()
                .error(R.drawable.bg)
                .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != dataList ? dataList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView itemTitle;

        protected RecyclerView recycler_view_list;

        protected Button btnMore;


        public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            this.recycler_view_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
            this.btnMore = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnMore);


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Trying to get some context here. Are you attempting to inflate a recycler view into a viewholder that is already in a recycler view?   Essentially it looks like you are implementing a nested recycler view. Is that correct?

Comment: I am using nested recycler view as used in playstore i want to click on more button as it is in playstore .When we click on more button .How we move to next Fragment uniQuely thats the thing i cannot understand

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are basing your first list off a
`private ArrayList<SectionDataModel> dataList`

You can use your position in the list to determine where to go. Based off your code you are attempting to add the click listener to the parent recycler view items. Those items have a More button that you would like to launch another intent.

If you are attempting launch an activity based on the items in the child recycler view you need to add your click listener in the SectionListDataAdapter.

Either way you can launch unique activities based on your position(CASE0). Or alternatively you can store the Class<?> definition of the intended Activity in your data model(CASE1).

```
itemRowHolder.btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Movies are Loading , " + sectionName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent moreIntent = new Intent();
                switch(i) {
                    case 0:
                        moreIntent.setClass(context, FirstActivity.class);
                    break;
                    case 1:
                        moreIntent.setClass(context, dataList.get(i).getMoreClass());
                    break;
                }
                startActivity(moreIntent);
            }
        });
```

I think this is what you are looking for Let me know if this helps or if it is off base. Screen shots might clarify what you are attempting to do.

Comment: i am just seding you a link of snapshot suggest me how can i made this

Comment: My solution should work for the situation that is described in your image. The more button is associated with the row in the parent recycler view. I am curious if the fragment for movie 1 and movie 2 are different fragments or identical fragments with different data? If identical fragments then you can pass the movie data into the fragment and let it decide how to display.

Answer (score 0):

> You achieve this by setting onClickListener to your adapter viewHolder, view code below. KOTLIN

```
holder.inventoryCard.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, NextActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("data", details) // you can use this line to pass data to the next class
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

> JAVA

```
holder.inventoryCard.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, NextActivity.class)
        intent.putExtra("data", details) // you can use this line to pass data to the next class
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
```